# How to write asp.net MVC Route for rewriting url like mysite.com/city-london.aspx?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have city page like this: mysite.com/city-london.aspx.
It's easy to make a route like mysite.com/city/london. But I must use city-london.aspx to support old URLs

How I make a route for this?. Below code doesn't work for me :-(. All I want is writing in RegisterRoutes

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "City",
            "city-{id}.aspx",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "City", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**UPDATE**:

Below code is working for me but I don't want to code this way.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var m = Regex.Match( Request.Url.AbsolutePath, @"/city-(.+?)\.aspx" );
        if (m.Success)
        {
            var path = "/?id=" + m.Groups[1].Value;
            Context.RewritePath(path, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code before default route,

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "City",
               url: "{pge}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "City" },
               constraints: new { pge = @"^city-[a-z]{1,10}.aspx$" }
           );
```

Comment: Thank you guy, when it comes to City Action, I will get page = "london.aspx". I can get the text "london" by split, replace...ect but what is the best (awesome) way to get the value "london"?

Answer (score 0):

*.aspx is a known extension by IIS, so it will be handled differently. If you remove the .aspx in the route definition, then browse to  mysite.com/city-london, it should just work. If it doesn't, please post the error if there's any.

Comment: I need to use .aspx to support old URLs (for SEO)

Comment: do you have any other routes before it? Is the any page showing up when u type in that url?